# SQL Insert data from .sql file to the table with CMD

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, insert, cmd

I want to insert data from an .sql file to my table in SQL. And all that with CMD.

My file contains that line:

```
INSERT INTO MYTABLE
VALUES (1, 2, 25, 'AK00008GP005L', '2008-04-19 11:31:00', '000', 1, 239.97, NULL, 'GH783MF', NULL, NULL);
```

It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: please specify the DB and the OS

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2008 R2. My DB name is TRY. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`SQLCMD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (as suggested by Sibster). Assuming the file containing the query is called `insert.sql`, the command in its simplest form (using NT authentication) would look something like:

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -E -d <dbname - TRY> -i insert.sql
```

To use SQL authentication:

```
sqlcmd -S <servername> -U <username> -P <password> -d <dbname - TRY> -i insert.sql
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) tool from microsoft.

A example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

1. Open a command prompt window.
2. Type: `sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql`
3. Press ENTER.